# Object Reference error on build but... no location?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, build, compiler-errors

It's an aspx web site. It's Huuuge. Oftentimes, we won't see errors until building the entire site. But it's always told us *where* the error is.

This time, I'm getting an `Object reference not set to instance of an object.` error with file, no line, no location. Double clicking on the error just does... nothing.

`Error  3   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

I've tried a few things that I've found here and elsewhere but nothing seems to be helping out or giving me more information. I've tried change the verbosity of compiler/build messages but those goggles don't seem to help.

Edit: Very specifically, the first time I try to build the site after opening the project, it says it builds just fine. Trying to build it again causes the error. Closing VS (2013) and reopening the project allows a first time build success and subsequent builds are failures. It should also be noted that it's not actually building anything because it completes far far too quickly - almost instantly.

Can anyone give me some ideas on how to track this down?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the VS installation is completely broken. Banging on the keyboard like a monkey and then trying to build succeeds when it should not.